# Can you have page numbers and tiny top/bottom margins?

Tags: margins, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I've been given some very specific format requirements, I need to have a 0.5cm top margin while also having page numbers in the top right.

I've tried using `fancyhdr` to make this work, but the page numbers in `\rhead` disappear over the top boundary for top margins smaller than 1.5cm. Is there any way to move the page numbers further down?

This is what the top of a page needs to look like:
[image]

EDIT:

This is one way to do what I wanted:

```
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: @Iokus does the answer satisfy your requirement

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough in my question, I need the text to go all the way up to the 0.5cm margin. I've added a picture of what I mean.

Comment: @lokus did the answer meet your requirement

Answer (score 1):

With the `geometry` parameters you have given, the page numbers should be visible, and the text should go to the 0.5cm border.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage[letterpaper,
margin=1in,
headheight=0.5cm,
%showframe
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{myheadings}% Set default page style to user style

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\rhead{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\lipsum[1-25]% dummy text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using package `fancyhdr` with `\pagestyle{headings}` seems a bit strange to me.